# Azure Servicebus messageid is always null

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a fairly simply function that sends a message to an azure servicebus queue.

```
public async Task<string> SendMessagesToQueue(string serviceBusConnectionString, int message, string queueName)
    {
        try
        {
            QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            // Create a new brokered message to send to the queue
            var brokeredMessage = new Message($"Message {message}");

            // Send the message to the queue
            await queueClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
            // Delay by 10 milliseconds so that the console can keep up
            await Task.Delay(10);
            return brokeredMessage.MessageId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This works fine and drops the message into the queue. However, the brokeredMessage.MessageId is always null.

Is there a right/better way of retrieving the message id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MessageId is a property which you can set using the public setMessageId function in Message class .

In the latest version of the Java client , message id is being returned when you receive a message even if you dont set it . If you set it before sending the messages , you will get the same value back as message Id while receiving that message.

Answer (score 2):

MessageId is a property of a Brokered message which can be used for identifying the message in the queue during message reception.The messageId need not be unique for the messages in a Queue unless the Queue has requireduplicateDetection property enabled which may lead to loss of messages.
So if you send a message without messageId it will be autogenerated similar to the sequence number.

Answer (score 1):

I guess because of `MessageId` is a user-defined value. You can feel free to generate and assign it by yourself. [Brokered​Message.​Message​Id Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.messageid?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0)

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a way I can get the ID of the message in the queue ? Like Id=b192187a-52a9-45a6-ba6f-c4b32ec9eb45

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you just need to receive the message and get this `MessageId` from it. You can easily to do it like it shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#4-receive-messages-from-the-queue), for example.

Comment: You understood me right. However this is not a feature thats available on the Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus library

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent) library? Why don't you use the [default one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/4.1.2)?

Comment: @w2olves message.MessageId is available for both libraries. In the future, the there will be support for plugins and one of the plugins will allow you to register a message ID factory.

Answer (score 0):

MessageId is a property of Brokered Message. Brokered Message has two main properties System properties and Custom properties. Whereas MessageId is one of the custom properties. You can set the MessageId during message submission also you can edit it and resubmitted to another queue/topic. It does not have any specific format. it can be string, guid, integer. Also, MessageId need not be unique whereas SequenceNumber is the one which is unique for messages in a queue.

You can use either WindowsAzure.ServiceBus or Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus libraries to perform messaging operation. In which WindowsAzure.ServiceBus doesn't support .Net Core applications but Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus would support