# Service Bus Trigger Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am trying to read messageid from Service bus message below.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
namespace DemoProject
{
    public class ServiceBusRequest : ILoggingInformation
    {
        private LoggingInformation _loggingInformation;
        private Message _eventMessage;

        public ServiceBusRequest(Message eventMessage)
        {
            _eventMessage = eventMessage;
            InitializeMethod();
        }

        private void InitializeMethod()
        {
            _loggingInformation= new LoggingInformation();
            _loggingInformation.CID= _eventMessage.MessageId;
        }
    }
}
```

But _eventMessage.MessageId value is null as well as values for _eventMessage it self is null.
Can any body Help me out with this.

Comment: Considering `_eventMessage` is `null`, you would want to check how/where you are initializing this class. You will have to share more of your code to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageId` is a user-defined value that Service Bus can use to identify duplicate messages, if enabled. You can generate the `MessageID` before sending the message and receive the same.

Reference: [MessageID property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.messageid?view=azure-dotnet), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552838/azure-servicebus-messageid-is-always-null)